# ACF WordPress: Foreach: data-type = 'group'

Tags: wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I have a problem with foreach with data-type = ‘group’.
I have several fields of type "group". In each group I have sub-fields: photo and WYSIWYG editor. I would like the loop to return to: `<div class "slider-nav-box-big">`, fields for one group, but I don't know how to refer to an array in a loop and how to define specific types of values e.g. images, WYSIWYG instead of value itself.
Can I define value differently?
I have this:

```
<?php

        $fields = get_field_objects();

        ?>

        <?php if ($fields): ?>
            <div class="slider slider-for">
                <?php foreach ($fields as $field): ?>

                    <?php if ($field['value']): ?>
                        <div class="slider-nav-box-big" id="<?php echo $field['name']; ?>">
                            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-12 slider-for-img">
                                <img src="<?php echo $field['value']; ?>" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-12 slider-for-description">
                                <p>
                                    <span><?php echo $field['label']; ?></span>
                                    <?php echo $field['wysiwyg']; ?>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

`$field[‘value’]` obviously returns an empty Array, and `$field[‘wysiwyg’]` doesn’t work at all.

Answer (score 0):

ACF actually provides examples of how to use a group and to display said data.

Their documentation can be found here on how to do just that - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/

Comment: Yes, I know this documentation, but these are examples for specific groups with a specific name, and I need some loop that will throw out all the groups. I have a solution - switch. I am giving below.

Answer (score 0):

I already have the solution, I give it if someone else needs it.
I had to use the switch in the foreach loop to check the field type as follows:

```
<?php
$fields = get_field_objects();
if( $fields ): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $fields as $field ): ?>
            <?php

             switch ($field['type']) {    
                 case "image":        
                 //do something for images      
                 break;    

                 case "wysiwyg":        
                 //do something here      
                 break;    

                 case "file":        
                 //do something here      
                 break;    

                 default:        
                 //end
                }?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```